# Pass Gesture in UIView To UICollectionView if its Swipe Right or Left

Tags: swift, uiview, gesture, uievent

Im trying to pass the gesture from `UIView` to the underneath  `UICollectionView` only if its swipe right or left but i can't get that with hitTest method in `UIView` class:

```
-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView == self) {
        return self.bgImage;
    }
    return nil;


}
```

I just need to pass the gesture to the collectionView which is the `bgImage` in my code, if user is only swiping right or left.

I don't need to remove the vertical swipe from its superView because it has another effect.